# Какие права есть у www-data?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Необходимо оценить возможности пользователя www-data в системе с установленным Apache2 Ubuntu 18.04. В интернете написано, что ни заключаются в правах группы www-data. Как их можно посмотреть? Правильно ли утверждать, что по умолчанию у группы www-data есть rwx права только на директорию серевера (/etc/apache2)?

Comment: 1. неправильно написано. пользователь и группа — это разные сущности. 2. неправильно так утверждать. например, повсеместно присутствующие каталоги `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` подразумевают в подавляющем большинстве установок возможность читать/писать/исполнять любому пользователю системы. 3. сама постановка задачи — «оценить возможности» — ведёт в тупик. туда же ведёт и постановка вопроса «какие права есть у пользователя имярек».

Comment: Очень похоже, что ошибка молотка: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/191416